# Deploy High Trust Provider hosted Apps for SharePoint 2013 on subsite?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, app, apps-development

High Trust Provider hosted Apps (on IIS locally):

I deploy my app on SharePoint like `(http://servername:port)` and I found my app in root of site but when i entered the subsite like `(http://servername:port/en)` or any other subsite I cannot find the app in apps available and also cannot find my app part in apps also.

How I can deploy my app to all site collection include subsites and sub of subsites like when deploy webpart.

I already Install apps from store and I can found them in all subsites like (Google Maps for SharePoint).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to deploy your apps using App Catalog for your web application. Then your app will be available on subsites too.

To configure your app catalog refer:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-help/use-the-app-catalog-to-make-custom-business-apps-available-for-your-sharepoint-online-environment-HA102772362.aspx

Comment: I did it as mention in link but I cannot find the app-part in subsite and when add app to subsite its gives me exception :
The provided App differs from another App with the same version and product ID.

Comment: First try to remove all instance of app where it is installed. If you are not able to remove it manually, [use the powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161233.aspx). Then in app manifest change product id to new guid and redeploy your app to app catalogue and then add it to subsite.